# Managing API endpoints for a website made with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, docker, nginx, endpoint

I have a website that I am working on using vanilla JS/HTML, I plan to eventually use docker to serve this site with nginx, and host this on some VM in the cloud.

While testing my site, I want my JavaScript to use a test endpoint running from my machine, for example `http://localhost/myapi/`

When running in production, I want my JavaScript to use a production endpoint, for example `http://example.com/myapi/`

Previously I have solved this by creating 2 different files, `test_endpoint.js`, and `prod_endpoint.js`, and copying them over simply as `endpoint.js` depending on an argument passed to my Dockerfile.

Is there a better way to manage test vs production endpoints given my setup?

Comment: You can set environment variables

Comment: @GrantHerman — In client-side JS?!

Comment: You've discovered (as we all have at some point) the need for some automation in our development environments. There are many, many ways to accomplish tasks similar to yours. Depending on your IDE, it may accomplish task very simply for your though a "refactor" menu for instance. You could use a simple task runner like Gulp to automate many things like this for you. You could go all out and use WebPack to do all sorts of automation tasks for you. For now, you might consider using [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com)

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/ you can pass environment variables with webpack. I think to the point above this one you are going to have to look into some external client side tools to have that switching ability.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting a base url in a variable depending on the url you're on? Like this:

```js
const api = window.location.host === 'localhost' ? 'http://localhost/myapi/' : 'http://example.com/myapi/';
```

And then use that variable everywhere you want to call your api:

```js
fetch(api + 'my/endpoint')
```

Comment: I guess this could work, but it seems a bit unreliable/hard to scale, what if eventually I have a whole set of endpoints, local testing, staging, production, different regions etc., I'm wondering about how this issue would actually be solved in a real world scenario

Comment: In real world scenarios we use `environment variables`, usually found in either a `.env` file on the server or some setting depending on where you have it hosted. That file (or setting) has the base url set in it, and the code reads that file first before running to get the base url. You can then have any number of environments, all with their own base url.